# Add unique constraint depending on value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a situation where i want to add unique constaint only when there is a certain value in other field
for example the table is
ID
CategoryName
Name
Value
CategoryID

the constraint will be on ID, CategoryName and Name only is CategoryID is 0

is it possible?

Comment: ID is always unique. Does not make sense to include it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_ID_CategoryName_Name, CategoryName, Name] ON TableName 
(
    ID, CategoryName, Name
)
WHERE (CategoryID = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to have two tables, one for `categoryId` 0 and one for the rest. You can define the uniqueness constraint on the first table, and use a view and union any time you want to use them as a single table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a filtered unique index on `Name` for `CategoryID = 0`.