# How to ensure that there are no duplicates in field? MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:
Customer (Id, Name, employeeID)

The table is already created and is empty, I don't want to remove duplicate data, all I want is to ALTER the table to ensure that there will be no duplicate data

I want to use ALTER and ensure that there are no duplicates in employeeID.

Will

```sql
ALTER TABLE Customers
UNIQUE(employeeID)
ADD CONSTRAINT
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you please tell me why downvote so I can edit my questions.

Comment: Not my DV, but it isn't really clear whether you're asking for a process that will de-duplicate a table full of existing data, or whether you're asking for a way to configure an empty table so that it cannot have duplicates inserted into a particular column

Comment: Why would a Customers table have an employee ID column? Much less a unique employee column- kinda means you'd need as many employees as you have customers (is the employeeid some kind of "the account manager for the customer")?

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you very much. It's just give to me this way. They told me that I have to esnure that there will be no dupicated in the field. Consider that the table is empty

Comment: If you have already duplicates in your table, craeting unique constraint won't work. You'd need to create custom [check constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017). Or you could create some insert trigger, that will check for uniquenes of added data.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn The table is empty

Comment: @MichałTurczyn.. what about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933196/how-to-ensure-that-there-are-no-duplicates-in-field-ms-sql-server-2014/55935854#55935854).?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a unique constraint will ensure that no duplicate entries will be added in future:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
ADD CONSTRAINT choose_a_name_for_the_constraint UNIQUE (EmployeeID);
```

You had it basically right, just a bit of a keyword order problem..

If you're working with SQLS, consider also that trivial operations like this can be done via the GUI in SSMS, and it will guide the process. You can also get it to turn the changes into scripts for you by right clicking the table and choosing "Script Table As..." so you can use them elsewhere

Comment: Is it possible to do it like: ALTER TABLE Customers
UNIQUE(employeeID)
ADD CONSTRAINT  ... Or it's wrong syntax?

Comment: Generally, keywords have to be specified in a particular order. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, I create [Unique Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806361/add-unique-constraint-depending-on-value-in-sql) as follows,

```
create table unicondtional (
 i int identity (1,1) 
 , j int 
)

insert into unicondtional values (1), (1) 

select * from unicondtional 

-- assume 'unicondtional' is table like what you have, so far. 

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX unique_with_condition ON unicondtional 
(
    j
)
WHERE (i > 2) -- max (i) 

-- create unique index with condition. 
-- from the 'where' clause, we say that, Index should be ensure the unique value insertion. 

insert into unicondtional values (1), (2), (3) -- See the Note.
-- successful insert. 

select * from unicondtional 

insert into unicondtional values (2)
-- due to the Unique Index, duplicate is not allowed by the Index.

update unicondtional 
set j = 3 
where j = 1 
-- before the Index(On the first two rows), duplicates are exist.  

select * from unicondtional
```

So, you don't need to delete the existing duplicate records.

**Note:** After the Index, if you consider the `1` as duplicate, then you go with `Trigger` instead of `Unique Index`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your table is empty, you can directly run

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_EmployeeID UNIQUE(EmployeeId);
```

That will ensure there is no duplicate `EmployeeId` can be added in that table.

But if there is some data in the table and there is already a duplicate `EmployeeId` you will get an error message

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'Customers' and the index name 'UQ_EmployeeId'. The duplicate key value is ("DuplicateValueHere").

For your question

> Is there a better way?

You already have the better way to prevent inserting duplicates.

---

See
**[`Create Unique Constraints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-2017#BeforeYouBegin)**
 and 
**[`ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**